# How to position Layers in swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to position a circular progress bar but I am failing constantly. I guess I am not understanding the concept of frames and views and bounds. I found this post on stack overflow that shows me exactly how to construct a circular progress bar.

However, in the post, a circleView was created as UIView using CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)

In my case, manually setting the x and y coordinates is obv a big no. So the circleView has to be in the centre of it's parent view.

Here is my view hierarchy:

```
view -> view2ForHomeController -> middleView -> circleView
```

So everything is positioned using auto layout. Here is the problem:The circleView is adding properly and it positions itself at the x and y value I specify but how can I specify the x and y values of the center of middleView. I tried the following but the center values are returned as 0.0, 0.0.

```
self.view.addSubview(self.view2ForHomeController)
self.view2ForHomeController.fillSuperview()

let xPosition = self.view2ForHomeController.middleView.frame.midX 
let yPostion = self.view2ForHomeController.middleView.frame.midY
print(xPosition) // ------- PRINTS ZERO
print(yPostion)  // ------- PRINTS ZERO

let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPostion, width: 100, height: 100))
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
self.view2ForHomeController.middleView.addSubview(circle)

var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()
progressCircle.frame = self.view.bounds

let lineWidth: CGFloat = 10
let rectFofOval = CGRect(x: lineWidth / 2, y: lineWidth / 2, width: circle.bounds.width - lineWidth, height: circle.bounds.height - lineWidth)

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rectFofOval)

progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ()
progressCircle.path = circlePath.cgPath
progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
progressCircle.lineWidth = 10.0
progressCircle.frame = self.view.bounds
progressCircle.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap(rawValue: "round")

circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)
circle.transform = circle.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/2)

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 1.1
animation.duration = 1
animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)

progressCircle.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Frame is in terms of superview/superlayer coordinates. If you are going to say

```
circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)
```

then you must give `progressCircle` a `frame` in terms of the `bounds` of `circle.layer`.

As for centering, in general, to center a sublayer in its superlayer you say:

```
theSublayer.position = CGPoint(
    x:theSuperlayer.bounds.midX, 
    y:theSuperlayer.bounds.midY)
```

And to center a subview in its superview you say:

```
theSubview.center = CGPoint(
    x:theSuperview.bounds.midX, 
    y:theSuperview.bounds.midY)
```

Comment: Yes, if you see the code that is what I have done. Problem is trying to calculate the x and y coordinates of the parent view. First 6 lines of my code will tell you where I am stuck

Comment: No it is not at all what you’ve done. You are saying `progressCircle.frame = self.view.bounds`. That’s totally wrong as I’ve said in my answer.

Comment: Yea changing that did not have any effect. Like I said, the problem is not in constructing the layer or view. It is all working fine and when I manually specify x and y coordinates, I am able to position it manually. Question is how can I position it at the centre of its superview. Thanks for the suggestion to change that though :)

Comment: Okay, added info about how to center something.

Answer (score 1):

The bounds are the layer/view's coordinates in its local coordinate system.  The frame is the layer/view's coordinates in its parents coordinate system.  Since layers do not participate in auto layout, you should implement `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews` (or `UIView.layoutSubLayers`) and set the `frame` of the layer to the `bounds` of its super layer's view (the backing layer of a UIView essentially is the CoreGraphics version of that view).

This also means you need to recompute your path in they layout method.  if that is expensive then draw your path in unit space and use the transform of the layer to scale it up to the view's dimensions instead.

Comment: That was useful info however, I am a rookie and even though reading tons of documentation, I simply make errors when involving layers. If you see the code, I am able to successfully create a circle view and position a circular progress bar inside. Only issue is how can I position this entire circle view package with the layer right at the centre of middleView? If I manually type x = 100 and y = 100. it works but I want to automatically calculate the centre of middleView and place it there. tried layoutsubviews and did not not work. Def doing something wrong here. Any answer?

Comment: To give more clarity, I first add view2ForHomeController and then the fillSuperView(). This view2ForHomeController consists of a subview which is middleView. I need to add the circleView to the centre of this middleView

Comment: If you simple breeze through the first 6 lines of code I have posted, you will understand where I am struggling :)

Comment: Your code does not contain enough context for me to determine but its likely that you are doing this in viewDidLoad or init and that your frame is zero because auto layout has not happened yet; thats why you need to calculate the position and size in viewDidLayoutSubviews or layoutSublayers.  I have an example here: https://github.com/joshuajhomann/RingProgressView/blob/master/RingView.playground/Contents.swift

Comment: Thanks Josh and yes I have checked this article too. That's right I am doing it in viewDidLoad. And I tried the same in viewDidlayout as well. Guess I will just keep looking :)

Comment: The "first 6 lines of code" include a call to a completely unknown method `fillSuperview()` so they tell us nothing. It is up to you to include all the code needed for anyone to _reproduce_ your issue.

Comment: @matt - Oh .. didn't know that that could be unclear. This is all happening within a closure in viewDidLoad and hence the "self" everywhere. I am adding a UIView class known as view2ForHomeController and I am simply setting it to fill the superview.

Comment: @JoshHomann Oh and so sorry, that link directed me to another stackover flow post. Which is weird. It worked now and I saw your implementation. Will definitely try that and update you. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first add the subviews and then create the entire circular progress view at

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     // Add and position the circular progress bar and its layers here
}
```